# sh: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

Tags: node.js, sh

I feel like a real moron posting a syntax error question but I really don't know how to fix this one

I'm trying to setup a build process in my node package.json file with the following script

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "NODE_ENV=production { echo '// mypkg-x.y.z'; browserify -r ./client/main.js:mypkg | uglifyjs -cm; } > dist/mypkg.min.js"
}
```

which runs the following in sh

```
NODE_ENV=production { echo '// mypkg-0.0.0'; browserify -r ./client/main.js:mypkg | uglifyjs -cm; } > dist/mypkg.min.js
```

sh error outupt

```
sh: -c: line 0: syntax error near unexpected token `}'
```

When I run the command in `bash` it works just fine, but nodejs uses `sh` :{

---

**End Goal**

I am browserifying some javascript code and I want to prefix the bundled output with the package's name/version

```
// mypkg-x.y.z
<bundle output here>
```

Comment: What about making a symlink so that bash is used instead (`mkdir -p ~/bin && ln -s /bin/bash ~/bin/sh && export PATH=$HOME/bin:$PATH `)? Also make sure to add the export to your `~/.bash_profile`/`~.bashrc` to make it permanent.

Comment: I'd rather not do that. I don't want to have to modify every environment my package is built on.

Comment: Apologies if this is a silly question, but is this an `npm` script? I don't recognize the `build` attribute, but I use many similar scripts that do the same thing you're trying to do but I use `postinstall`.

Comment: Well, file a [new issue](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/new) about it or [submit a pull request](https://github.com/npm/npm/pulls) then.

Comment: @mscdex it's not an npm issue. There's a syntax error in the `sh` script I've written. I just don't know where.

Comment: @Antiga you can define your own scripts and run them using `npm run build` or `npm run myscript`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a semicolon after you set `NODE_ENV`:

```
"build": "NODE_ENV=production; { echo '// mypkg-x.y.z'; browserify -r ./client/main.js:mypkg | uglifyjs -cm; } > dist/mypkg.min.js"
```

Comment: Nailed it. Thanks, @Ray.

Answer (score 0):

@Ray's answer worked great, I just wanted to post an alternate solution to the same problem

```
// this works too !
{ echo '// mypkg-0.0.0'; NODE_ENV=production browserify -r ./client/main.js:mypkg | uglifyjs -cm; } > dist/mypkg.min.js
```

To highlight the difference, all I did was move the `NODE_ENV=production` bit to just before the `browserify` bit. In this case, no semicolon is needed.

This is actually a little specific to my use case too, as the environment variable is only needed for that part of the build process.